# How to get rows of max(count(*)) with inner select

Tags: mysql, count, max

I have a query that gets the max count of an inner select grouped by three fields. Now I don't only want to have the number, but the whole rows. I just can't figure it out. Here is the query that returns the number:

```
SELECT MAX (count) FROM
(SELECT COUNT (*) AS count,
        field1,
        field2,
        field3   
    FROM someScheme.someTable
    GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
     ) AS counts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, field1, field2, field3   
FROM someScheme.someTable
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  this only returns one example of the maximum.

If you want all possible rows, then it is more complicated:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, field1, field2, field3   
FROM someScheme.someTable
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt)
                   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
                         FROM someScheme.someTable
                         GROUP BY field1, field2, field3
                        ) t
                  );
```